# Quelle est la difference entre "le savais-tu" et "sais-tu" ?

Tags: sens

Not sure what is the difference between those two.
I am reading a book and I can see few times they refer to le savais-tu?
one thing that I am also puzzled is why do they use LE savais tu not just savais-tu.
Anyone can explain thanks.

Comment: Please ask one question per question.  The difference between tenses is not related to the pronoun (what do you think it means?); please give more context.

Comment: *Did you know it?* vs. *Do you know (it)?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Le savais-tu ?"* signifie *"Did you know this/that?"*.

*"Savais-tu"* signifie simplement *"Did you know"* et nécessite un complément afin d'en faire une phrase correcte.

Answer (score 1):

*Did you know it?* and *Do you know?* are interpretations of *le savais-tu ?* and *sais-tu ?*